# How to make a child process survive service shutdown?

Tags: python, systemd, nohup

`script1.py`:

```
#do somthing
os.system('nohup python3 -u script2.py {} {} >> {}.out &'.format(xxx, yyy, zzz))
#do somthing
```

`script2.py`:
this scipt always run with `loop.run_forever()`

When script1 run as a service, this script runs script2 correctly.
But if i kill Script1 with 'kill pid' command, Script2 will also be killed automatically, which I do not want and I want Script2 to continue working.

Edit: I use `systemd` for running `script1.py`

Comment: Which specific process supervision system are you using? If it's systemd, f/e, there are configurable options about how children get killed. If whatever process supervision system you're using is shutting down the whole cgroup, `nohup` doesn't do anything to switch cgroups, so there you are.

Comment: BTW, using `os.system` is generally frowned on -- the `subprocess` module is a strict superset: It can do everything `os.system` can and much, _much_ more (including, importantly, not invoking a shell; the code above is prone to serious security problems if `xxx`, `yyy` or `zzz` are user-controlled; to fix that while still using a shell you'd need to substitute in `shlex.quote(xxx)`, not just `xxx`).

Comment: @charles-duffy Hi thanks, so I do with subprocess.
And about my problem, I use systemd
Can you explain more fully what I should do?

Comment: See the `KillMode` option in systemd. Setting it to `process` is the most conservative choice, in terms of approaches least likely to kill things other than your process yourself. If you edit the detail that you're using systemd into your question, I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want child processes you start to not be killed by systemd, change the `KillMode` configured for your service. Thus, in your service file:

```
[Service]
KillMode=process
```

The default value is `KillMode=control-group`, such that systemd kills everything in the cgroup it created for the service; and `nohup` doesn't know anything about cgroups.